# Binding a groupbox with checkboxes inside

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, converters, groupbox

For a WPF-application that I am writing with my projectgroup I need to check in xaml if multiple checkboxes are selected. If the checkboxes are selected, than the content of the checkbox should be placed in the database.

I hope that the following code gives a little indication of what I want to do. Below the code I will explain a little bit more of what I thought that I needed to do to get the content of the checkboxes in the database.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CheckboxesWerkvormToDBConverter x:Key="WerkvormToDB" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/ModuleStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Border BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <GroupBox Header="Werkvorm">
        <UniformGrid Columns="6" Rows="2">
            <CheckBox Content="Excursie"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Groepswerk"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Gesprek"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Hoorcollege"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Tutoruur"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Zelfstudie"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Individueel"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Practicum"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Projectuur"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Theorie"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Werkcollege"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Workshop"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </GroupBox>
</Border>
```

My Teacher said that the best way to put the content of the checkboxes in a database is with a converter. Now I am trying to bind a converter to the groupbox with checkboxes, that if one or multiple checkboxes are selected I can convert them to the contentstring for the database.The problem was that I could not find anything on the internet of how to bind a groupbox with checkboxes inside. What I could find was how to check if the checkboxes are selected one by one, but this would lead to too much code and because of that is not the solution that I want.

Now I was hoping that somebody could help me solving this problem. Tutorials, guides, any kind of information will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to follow the MVVM pattern (model - view - viewmodel). Then, you can easily store your data in the database using the viewmodel's routines.

Comment: you want the checked boxes content to be added to the database globally (at once), shouldn't be more appropriate to have a button or something to fire the operation !!